# React js close Modal on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

In my Next js app I created a Modal. this modal closes when clicked outside of the modal container. but how can i make it close itself when the user scroll outside?

Page.js

```
const [showTypeModal, setShowTypeModal] = useState(false);

const handleTypeModalClose = () => setShowTypeModal(false);

<TypeModal onClose={handleTypeModalClose} visible={showTypeModal} />
```

TypeModal.js component

```
const handleOnClose = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === "container" || e.target.id === "inner") onClose();
  };
  if (!visible) return null;

return (
    <div
      id="container"
      onClick={handleOnClose}
      className="fixed top-44 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 bg-gray-400 bg-opacity-30 backdrop-blur-sm hidden md:flex"
    >
      <div id="inner" className="w-3/6" onClick={handleOnClose} />
      <div className="h-[60%] w-1/5 bg-white drop-shadow-md rounded-3xl flex flex-col justify-evenly items-start overflow-auto">
        {homeType.map((type) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={type.id}
              onClick={() => dispatch(addType(type.name))}
              className="hover:bg-[#f0fcfb] cursor-pointer w-full h-14 pl-10  last:rounded-b-3xl first:rounded-t-3xl flex items-center"
            >
              {type.name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

what i want is that when user scrolls in the "container" div it closes but not in the "inner" div.

i've tried useEffect but this closes on all scroll.

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onClose);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onClose);
  }, []);
```

Comment: This question was wrongfully flagged as duplicate because Modals act differently. For anyone with this problem, you can set the "OnWheel" event of the parent container to close the modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `ref` for the `container` element, and `scroll` event on it instead of the whole `window`.

```
  import { useRef } from 'react';

  // ... code

  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div
      id="container"
      onClick={handleOnClose}
      className="fixed top-44 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 bg-gray-400 bg-opacity-30 backdrop-blur-sm hidden md:flex"
      ref={containerRef}
    >
      <div id="inner" className="w-3/6" onClick={handleOnClose} />
      <div className="h-[60%] w-1/5 bg-white drop-shadow-md rounded-3xl flex flex-col justify-evenly items-start overflow-auto">
        {homeType.map((type) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={type.id}
              onClick={() => dispatch(addType(type.name))}
              className="hover:bg-[#f0fcfb] cursor-pointer w-full h-14 pl-10  last:rounded-b-3xl first:rounded-t-3xl flex items-center"
            >
              {type.name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
)
```

And inside `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
      if (containerRef.current) {
      containerRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", onClose);
        return () => containerRef.current.removeEventListener("scroll", onClose);
    }
  }, [containerRef]);
```

Comment: sorry, it's not working

Comment: @MohammedBekele, it looks like something wrong in your end, if you can make a live example on any live editors like `codesandbox` we can help you more.

Comment: Hi, is it resolved for you ? pls let me know i m also looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

Just add the on Scroll event  on your main div or wherever you want and call your setState and make the modal false .

```
<div
  id="container"
  onScroll={handleOnClose}
  onClick={handleOnClose}
  className="fixed top-44 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 bg-gray-400 bg-opacity-30 backdrop-blur-sm hidden md:flex"
>
  <div id="inner" className="w-3/6" onClick={handleOnClose} />
  <div className="h-[60%] w-1/5 bg-white drop-shadow-md rounded-3xl flex flex-col justify-evenly items-start overflow-auto">
    {homeType.map((type) => {
      return (
        <div
          key={type.id}
          onClick={() => dispatch(addType(type.name))}
          className="hover:bg-[#f0fcfb] cursor-pointer w-full h-14 pl-10  last:rounded-b-3xl first:rounded-t-3xl flex items-center"
        >
          {type.name}
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
```

Comment: it didn't work.